# How to wait for the dialog need to be false in protractor?

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

The scenario is, If the user fill the detail in the form (it displays in the dialog), it will call the API to store it. If the post is successful the dialog get close. After that I need to search an input box for the entry.

Now the problem what I am facing is, When I click the input box I am getting the following error

`<input _ngcontent-c16="" formcontrolname="description" id="description" pinputtext="" class="ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-widget
ng-valid ui-state-filled ng-untouched ng-pristine"> is not clickable at point (790, 240). Other element would receive the click: <div _ngcontent-c16="" class="ui-grid-col-5">...</div>`

This is because of the dialog box. If I set the timeout, some times it is working. If the response is delayed it giving the same error.

So I am trying to wait for the protractor till the dialog need to be closed. So I tried the following thing but it is not working

```
var dialog = element(by.className('well well-sm'));
await browser.wait(expect(await dialog.isDisplayed()).toBe(true));
```

How can I solve this problem.?

Answer (score 0):

if you need the dialog to be closed before proceeding, you'd need to wait for it to be displayed/present = false

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;  

var dialog = element(by.className('well well-sm'));
await browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(dialog));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;  

var dialog = element(by.className('well well-sm'));
await browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf(dialog));
```

stalenessOf: An expectation for checking that an element is not attached to the DOM of a page. This is the opposite of 'presenceOf'.